# Root systems and weight lattices with PStricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

(Edit: See below)

I am trying to draw a simple picture containing a [root system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system), [Weyl chambers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_group#Weyl_chambers) and root/weight lattice using `pstricks`. I am essentially trying to construct something like figures 6.5, 6.6 and 6.7 (pages 193-196) in [these lecture notes](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmf/Teaching/Lectures/EDC.pdf). I have been able to do most of it:

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)\psset{unit=1.3}
    \psset{linewidth=1.5pt}
        %Weyl Chambers
        \pscustom[linewidth=0pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray]{
            \psline(0,3)(0,0)
            \psline(0,0)(2.6,1.5)
        }
            \psline[linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1pt](0,-3)(0,3)
            \psline[linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1pt](-2.6,-1.5)(2.6,1.5)
            \psline[linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1pt](2.6,-1.5)(-2.6,1.5)

        %Roots
        \psline{->}(0,0)(2,0) \psline{->}(0,0)(-2,0)
        \psline{->}(0,0)(-1,1.732) \psline{->}(0,0)(1,-1.732)
        \psline{->}(0,0)(1,1.732) \psline{->}(0,0)(-1,-1.732)

        %Fundamental Weights
        \psline[linewidth=1pt]{->}(0,0)(0,1)
        \psline[linewidth=1pt]{->}(0,0)(0.866,0.5)

\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

but I have problems constructing the weight lattice, like the ones in the lecture notes. Is there a simple way to include this? (It's the lattice spanned by the fundamental weights, the small arrows).

---

A small bonus question (sorry for asking two questions at once). Many people seem to like TikZ, but I have never used it. Would such a drawing be simpler to draw using TikZ?

---

**Edit:** cmhughes has given a very good and useful answer, but as I have written in the comment I still have a small problem with it. What I want is, given two vectors $a = (a_1, a_2)$ and $b = (b_1,b_2)$, to construct the lattice $n_1 a + n_2 b$ where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are integers. Using `multido`, I can only make this work if the components of $a$ and $b$ are integers and can be decomposed into square lattices (as in cmhughes example). In other words, figure 6.5 seems to be harder to construct in a simple way than figure 6.6. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: `multido` can also handle non integer. (see documentation). You can also use `\psplot` and then use the postscript loop. My problem: I am not a mathematician and most of your explanation I can't understand ;-)

Comment: @Marco Oh you are right, thanks a lot. Half of the problem solved! I still need to construct a lattice where the red/white sub-lattices  aren't square lattices (see figure 6.5 in the lecture notes). But I can try to do it myself now. And good point, I will try to use less mathematical terminology in the future. :)

Comment: Do you know the package [`pst-cox`](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pst-cox/?idsec=en).

Comment: @Heidar: Would you like me to post code for Figure 6.5? I think my code could be adapted.

Comment: @Marco No, I didn't know it but it looks quit useful. Not sure how to use it for this problem though.

Comment: @cmhughes That would be great! My problem is I don't know how to change it to figure 6.5.

Comment: @Heidar: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Dilaton Thanks for letting me know, I will definitely check it out!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is a replication of Figure 6.6 in your linked document. Note the use of `multido`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(16,16)
\psset{unit=0.7}
%\psgrid % very useful when constructing!
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue](0,0)(16,16)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue](0,16)(16,0)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue](0,8)(16,8)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue](8,0)(8,16)
    \multido{\nx=5+2}{4}{\psdot[linecolor=red,dotstyle=o,dotsize=0.2](\nx,15)}%
    \multido{\nx=4+2}{5}{\psdot[linecolor=red,dotsize=0.2](\nx,14)}%
    \multido{\nx=3+2}{6}{\psdot[linecolor=red,dotstyle=o,dotsize=0.2](\nx,13)}%
    \multido{\ny=4+2}{5}{%
        \multido{\nx=2+2}{7}{\psdot[linecolor=red,dotsize=0.2](\nx,\ny)}%
        }
    \multido{\ny=5+2}{4}{%
        \multido{\nx=1+2}{8}{\psdot[linecolor=red,dotstyle=o,dotsize=0.2](\nx,\ny)}%
        }
    \multido{\nx=2+2}{7}{\psdot[linecolor=red,dotsize=0.2](\nx,4)}%
    \multido{\nx=3+2}{6}{\psdot[linecolor=red,dotstyle=o,dotsize=0.2](\nx,3)}%
    \multido{\nx=4+2}{5}{\psdot[linecolor=red,dotsize=0.2](\nx,2)}%
    \multido{\nx=5+2}{4}{\psdot[linecolor=red,dotstyle=o,dotsize=0.2](\nx,1)}%
    \rput(3,15){$\rho_1$}
    \rput(1,13){$\rho_{12}$}
    \rput(1,3){$\rho_{121}$}
    \rput(3,1){$\rho_{1212}=\rho_{2121}$}
    \rput(13,1){$\rho_{212}$}
    \rput(15,3){$\rho_{21}$}
    \rput(15,14){$\rho_{2}$}
    \psline[linecolor=black,arrows=->](8,8)(8,10)
    \psline[linecolor=black,arrows=->](8,8)(9,9)
    \psline[linecolor=gray,arrows=->](8,8)(10,8)
    \psline[linecolor=gray,arrows=->](8,8)(6,10)
    \uput[270](10,8){$\alpha_2$}
    \uput[0](9,9){$\lambda_1$}
    \uput[45](8,10){$\lambda_2$}
    \uput[45](6,10){$\alpha_2$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need the arrows to be on top of the dots, simply change their ordering in the code.

**UPDATE**

I have recreated Figure 6.5 below. As previously, I imagine that there are more clever/elegant/robust ways to achieve it; I've often found that trying to shortcut can cost me more time than going the long way round. Here is the process I used:

- found the equation of the lines that the dots lie on
- plotted the dots on the lines
- clipped everything outside of the hexagon

AFAIK, `\psdot` can not take algebraic expressions, so I had to use RPN. If someone knows better, please let me know.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
 \tiny
\psset{unit=0.7}
%\psgrid % very useful when constructing!

% plot the lines
\psset{algebraic=true}
\psplot[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue]{-5}{5}{0.5*x}
\psplot[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue]{-5}{5}{-0.5*x}
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue](0,-5)(0,5)

% shaded region
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue]{
            \psline(0,0)(0,4)
            \psline(0,4)(4,2)
            \psline(4,2)(0,0)}

 % clip everything outside of the hexagon
\begin{psclip}{\pspolygon[linestyle=none](-4.5,-2.5)(-4.5,2.5)(0,4.5)(4.5,2.5)(4.5,-2.5)(0,-4.5)}
% plot the HOLLOW dots
\multido{\nx=-4+1}{9}%
{%
    \multido{\nb=-4+1}{10}%
    {%
        % ordered pair: (\nx, 0.5\nx + \nb)
        \psdot[linecolor=red,dotsize=0.4,dotstyle=o](!\nx\space dup 0.5 mul \nb\space add)
    }%
}%

% plot the SOLID dots
\multido{\nx=-4+1}{9}%
{%
    \multido{\nb=-6+3}{5}%
    {%
        % ordered pair: (\nx, 3/2*\nx+\nb)
        \psdot[linecolor=red,dotsize=0.4](!\nx\space dup 2 div 3 mul \nb\space add)
    }%
}%
\end{psclip}

% other stuff
\psline[linecolor=gray,arrows=->](0,0)(2,0)
\psline[linecolor=gray,arrows=->](0,0)(-1,1.5)
\psline[linecolor=black,arrows=->](0,0)(0,1)
\psline[linecolor=black,arrows=->](0,0)(1,0.5)
\rput(-3,-4){$\rho_{121}=\rho_{212}$}
\rput(3,-4){$\rho_{21}$}
\rput(5,0){$\rho_2$}
\rput(-5,0){$\rho_{12}$}
\rput(-3,4){$\rho_{1}$}
\uput[270](1,0.5){$\lambda_1$}
\uput[315](0,1){$\lambda_2$}
\uput[225](2,0){$\alpha_1$}
\uput[0](-1,1.5){$\alpha_2$}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't doubt that there are cleverer ways of achieving this- I look forward to seeing them!

Comment: It is also possible to specify the nodes using polar coordinates (if you so wish) using `(r;t)`. For this you need `\SpecialCoor` and `\degrees[n]`, depending on your preference.

Comment: cmhughes: Just curious, how long did it take you or would it have taken you if you had put this code together from scratch to the end? I am wondering because I am learning `tikz` package currently and have not created anything with it yet, but would like to know on average how long would it take one to create something like this as a benchmark, so I can record my progress from how long it takes me when I make my first task and as I get better, I can track my speed to see if I am also getting faster (i.e., length of time it is taking me to complete the job).

Comment: @cmhughes Amazing picture, thanks a lot. But I have a small question. Before I asked the question I was almost able to construct the lattice myself using `\multido`, but your example avoids the problem I had. How about if the position of the lattice points can't be specified by integers and you need something like `\multido{\ny=4+2}{5}{\multido{\nx=2+2}{7}{\psdot(1.45*\nx, 1.2*\ny)}}`, or even other mathematical expressions like `\psdot(1.45*\nx - sqrt(3)*\ny, Cos(120)*\ny)`. Is this possible?

Comment: @Werner Nice, I didn't know one could use polar coordinates. This makes my life simpler, thanks!

Comment: @nightowl: I've been using `PSTricks` for about a year- this picture took me about 30 minutes, and I built it from scratch.

Comment: @Heidar: Thanks! It might be possible with the `calc` package, or perhaps using RPN. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Heidar: When using `\SpecialCoor`, you can use postscript RPN notation in your nodes. Prefix the postscript code using `!`, as in `\psdot(! <ps>)`.

Comment: @cmhughes: Rather use `linestyle=none` than `linecolor=white` to clip the diagram; you'll notice the white line overlaid on the dashed lines which isn't ideal. Similarly for the shaded region: `linewidth=0pt` -> `linestyle=none`. Also, you don't need `\pstVerb` to use the variables `\nb` and `\nx`; you can use them directly in the ps coordinates: `\psdot[..](!\nx\space dup .5 mul \nb\space add)`. Finally, I'd rather just use `\psline` instead of plotting the 2 lines using `\psplot` since that requires the addition of the `pst-plot` package.

Comment: @cmhughes : I am really grateful for all your help, I'm amazed by the quality of tex.SE. This is exactly what I was looking for, so I can't do anything but accepting. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for your feedback- I've implemented all of your suggestions except removing the `pst-plot` package (got some errors without it, even after removing `\psplot`). @Heidar- you're welcome!

Answer (score 13):

Your original version of the question asked if this would be simpler in TikZ.  That got me thinking about how to do it, and I didn't notice that you'd edited that out until I'd gotten most of the way there.  So you can have this solution anyway!

Here's the result:

[image: Roots with TikZ]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30301/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

\pgfmathsetmacro\ax{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ay{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\bx{2 * cos(120)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\by{2 * sin(120)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lax{2*\ax/3 + \bx/3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lay{2*\ay/3 + \by/3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lbx{\ax/3 + 2*\bx/3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lby{\ay/3 + 2*\by/3}


\foreach \k in {1,...,6} {
  \draw[blue,dashed] (0,0) -- +(\k * 60 + 30:5.5);
}
\fill[blue!25] (0,0) -- (30:4 * \lby) -- (0,4 * \lby) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}
\clip (90:5) \foreach \k in {1,...,6} { -- ++([rotate=\k * 60 + 60]90:5) };
\foreach \na in {-3,...,2} {
  \foreach \nb in {-3,...,2} {
    \node[circle,fill=red] at (\na * \ax + \nb * \bx, \na * \ay + \nb * \by) {};
    \node[circle,draw=red] at (\lax + \na * \ax + \nb * \bx, \lay + \na * \ay + \nb * \by) {};
    \node[circle,draw=red] at (\lbx + \na * \ax + \nb * \bx, \lby + \na * \ay + \nb * \by) {};
  }
}
\end{scope}
\draw[gray,->] (0,0) -- (\ax,\ay) node[below left] {\(\alpha_1\)};
\draw[gray,->] (0,0) -- (\bx,\by) node[right] {\(\alpha_2\)};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (\lax,\lay) node[below] {\(\lambda_1\)};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (\lbx,\lby) node[below right] {\(\lambda_2\)};
\node at (0:5) {\(\rho_2\)};
\node at (120:5) {\(\rho_1\)};
\node at (180:5) {\(\rho_{12}\)};
\node at (-120:5) {\(\rho_{121} = \rho_{212}\)};
\node at (-60:5) {\(\rho_{21}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to try to follow the idea as much as possible.  So we define the key coordinates `(\ax,\ay)` and `(\bx,\by)` then the lambdas in terms of them.  We draw a segment of the lattice using the `\foreach`s to iterate over a chunk of the integers, and clip against a hexagonal region to only show that part that we want (the point of clipping is to avoid having to compute exactly which nodes to draw; if I weren't so lazy, I could figure it out beforehand).

Then there's a few labels to put in, and arrows to draw, but that's quite simple.

Comment: I have re-edited my question, and put that part back again. Your drawing looks amazing, I will definitely start learning TikZ since it seems to be more straightforward. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, a few hours ago I found your "braids" package. I have been looking for something like that for a few month now, really nice work. Looking forward to try it out.

Comment: TikZ is the only one that I learnt so I can't speak to the comparison.  It's certainly simpler *for me*.  Let me know how you get on with the braids package - I'm interested in feedback and knowing how it could be improved.

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok with TikZ, you can try the [rank-2-roots](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.7478.1535731234.5100.ctan-ann@ctan.org) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rank-2-roots}
\begin{document}
\foreach \system in {A,B,G}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{rootSystem}{\system}
\roots
\weightLattice{3}
\WeylChamber
\end{rootSystem}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```